# null fatal exception and SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out, Android sockets, mulitiple client

Tags: android, sockets

I have a Java desktop server and multiple Android tablet clients using sockets. each of the two or three clients sends a short text message to the server and the server sends a response message.  both short texts.

The server launches a separate thread for each client connection.

The problem is that I set up two clients and was sending text message from each of them and then one of the clients after sending some messages always freezes and stops being able to send or receive any more messages. not always but about 50% of the time.

I tried both adjusting the timeout time for the socket and added bufferedWriter to the output stream.  but both of these changes did not help.

Desktop java application, server I get:

```
致命的: Fatal excepiton, null, java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
```

one of the Android tablets, the client, I get:

```
 03-01 17:31:13.740: W/System.err(2992): java.net.SocketException: recvfrom failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)
```

Is there a common cause for this, or anything I can try?

full server logcat shown below:

```
2013/03/01 17:33:17 com.example.lotterygame.MultiThreader run
致命的: null
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:129)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:264)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:306)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:158)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:167)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:136)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:299)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:362)
    at jp.co.forever.lotterygame.MultiThreader.run(MultiThreader.java:43)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

EDIT,

added the line the null is coming from, in the server,

it is in the code below in the line --->  while((line = in.readLine())!= null){

```
    @Override
public void run() {
    try {       
        out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);

        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

     System.out.println("streams are setup from new thread\n");

     String line ="";

            while((line = in.readLine())!= null){

                SocketPack spk = new SocketPack(socket, line.trim());
                this.messageFromClient(spk);


            }

              out.close();
              in.close();
              socket.close();
    } // end run
    catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MultiThreader.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    } // end run

    public void messageFromClient(SocketPack msgc){
        this.setChanged();
        this.notifyObservers(msgc);
    }
```

Comment: The changes did help. You got a read timeout. Without seeing your code it is impossible to assist further.

Comment: i added some code, where the null is located

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'null' is coming from your own code, where you *log* null when you catch an IOException.

The relevant thing is the timeout, and that happens because you *set* a read timeout, and it happens, i.e. the peer didn't send anything within that time.

The 'connection reset' is probably a result of the timeout at the peer causing the peer to close the connection, and/or exit.